# Name of a kind of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers

Each line count the numbers in previous line:

1 
1 1
2 1
1 1, 1 2
3 1, 1 2
2 1, 1 2, 1 3
3 1, 2 2, 1 3
2 1, 2 2, 2 3
1 1, 4 2, 1 3

What is the name of a sequence obtained with this method?

Does anyone know a reference? (or similar topics)

Comment: This would be the most similar but only counts from left to right as opposed to the whole line. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this sequence on the OEIS - https://oeis.org/A005150. It instead writes the occurrence of the numbers in order.